# Why is my table getting errors?

Tags: tables, amsmath

I'm mystified by why I can't generate a simple tabular set of equations using `tabular`. As far as I can tell my code follows the example in the documentation exactly, simply substituting some slightly more complex expressions for the entries in the table.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
z_{\earth}(t) &= 0 \\
z_{\venus}(t) &=  R_{\venus} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} & + r_{\venus} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\venus} t +  k_{\venus})} \\
z_{\mercury}(t) &=  R_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} & + r_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\mercury} t + k_{\mercury})} \\
z_{\mars}(t) &= R_{\mars} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\mars} t + K_{\mars})} & + r_{\mars} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\jupiter}(t) &= R_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\jupiter} t + K_{\jupiter})} & + r_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\saturn}(t) &= R_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\saturn} t + K_{\saturn})} & + r_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}
\end{tabular}
$$

\end{document}
```

Why is my table getting errors? How do I get it to work?

Comment: tabular cells are not in math, you could use `array` instead but better would be to use, as you have tagged, the `amsmath` package and an environment such as  `align*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'd tried that (at least with `aligned`) but could't find a way to get control over left-right-center alignment in individual columns. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: are you sure you want to center the cells starting with `=` ? It would look very odd with differing space to the left and right of the =?

Comment: Do check out the posting [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for information about why one should not use `$$` directives in a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using an `array` environment instead of `tabular`, with care being taken to align the `=` and (if present) `+` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{array}              % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}  % dedicated column type for "+" symbols
\begin{document}    
\[  % please don't use "$$ ... $$" in a LaTeX document
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8} % for a more open look
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}     % no default inter-column spacing
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} lCl}
z_{\earth}(t) & 0 \\
z_{\venus}(t) &  R_{\venus} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}   
  & + & r_{\venus} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\venus} t + k_{\venus})} \\
z_{\mercury}(t) &  R_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} 
  & + & r_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\mercury} t + k_{\mercury})} \\
z_{\mars}(t) & R_{\mars} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\mars} t + K_{\mars})} 
  & + & r_{\mars} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\jupiter}(t) & R_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\jupiter} t + K_{\jupiter})} 
  & + & r_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\saturn}(t) & R_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\saturn} t + K_{\saturn})} 
  & + & r_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works nicely. Can you elaborate a bit on the magic you did there?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - The parameter `\arraycolsep` is set to `0pt` as we're providing our own customized spacing. The `@{{}={}}` directive automatically inserts a correctly spaced `=` symbol between columns 1 and 2 (of type `r` and `l`, respectively. By "correctly spaced", I mean spacing appropriate for an object of type math-rel. The `>{{}}c<{{}}` column type may be a bit intimidating looking, at least at first glance. What it does, in conjunction with the zero-width intercolumn space, is to create the right spacing for the column that contains the `+` symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Using amsmath `align*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
z_{\earth}(t) &= 0 \\
z_{\venus}(t) &=  R_{\venus} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}  + r_{\venus} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\venus} t +  k_{\venus})} \\
z_{\mercury}(t) &=  R_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}  + r_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\mercury} t + k_{\mercury})} \\
z_{\mars}(t) &= R_{\mars} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\mars} t + K_{\mars})}  + r_{\mars} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\jupiter}(t) &= R_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\jupiter} t + K_{\jupiter})}  + r_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\saturn}(t) &= R_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\saturn} t + K_{\saturn})}  + r_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The errors are mainly due to using `tabular` instead of `array`.

The easiest way to set the equations is with `alignat*`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
z_{\earth}(t) &= 0 \\
z_{\venus}(t) &=  R_{\venus} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}
 && + r_{\venus} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\venus} t +  k_{\venus})} \\
z_{\mercury}(t) &=  R_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}
 && + r_{\mercury} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\mercury} t + k_{\mercury})} \\
z_{\mars}(t) &= R_{\mars} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\mars} t + K_{\mars})}
 && + r_{\mars} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\jupiter}(t) &= R_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\jupiter} t + K_{\jupiter})}
 && + r_{\jupiter} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t} \\
z_{\saturn}(t) &= R_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i (\Omega_{\saturn} t + K_{\saturn})}
 && + r_{\saturn} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation. We set up two sets of “left-aligned and right-aligned” pairs of columns. The first alignment point is at the equals signs, the second one at the plus signs. The second right-aligned column is empty.

Contrary to `align*`, `alignat*` does not insert horizontal spaces between the column pairs. Contrary to `array`, it uses display math mode automatically.

If you need to give a number to the whole block, do

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
z_{\earth}(t) &= 0 \\
z_{\venus}(t) &=  R_{\venus} e^{2\pi i \Omega_{\astrosun} t}
 && + r_{\venus} e^{2\pi i (\omega_{\venus} t +  k_{\venus})} \\
<...same code as before...>
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
```

If you have to give a number to each line, change `alignat*` into `alignat`.

A final recommendation: never use `$$` in LaTeX. Never. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) for more information.